# Any word other than valid

Tags: regex-negation

I would like to match every other words in a sentence except the word "valid"

A sample sentence: i want to know all the valid request made in the last one week.

I am searching for a regex that matches each of the words in the sentence except "valid"

I have tried this ^(?!.*valid).*$ but not getting the result

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern seems to work:

```
\b(?!valid\b)\w*?\b
```

This uses a negative lookahead to assert that each word is something other than `valid`.

### Demo

Comment: Thank you Tim for your timely response. It worked but it is not matching the period/dot and space

Comment: The matching the space requirement doesn't make sense to me.  Which word owns the spaces before and after it?

Comment: the spaces in between every words in the sentence. " i want to know all the valid request made in the last one week."

Comment: In this case, it might be easier for you to just remove `valid` from the input.